# Prime number using functions in python error

Tags: python, function

Hello, I'm relatively new to Python. The code below generates a random number in python from 0 to 10. It then parses another function to determine if it is a prime, if it is not, generate a new number and repeat. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't seem to work?

Code:

```
import random
def gen ():
  x=random.randint(0,10)
  isprime (x)
  if isprime(x):
   return x
  else:
   gen()


def isprime (number):
 b = number - 1
 while True:
  if number > 1:
   if b == 1:
     return True
     break
   elif number % b == 0:
     return False
   b = b-1
  else:
   return False

g = gen()
g
```

Comment: Couple random notes : The first `isprime (x)` in your code is not doing anything. Running the isprime loop from 2 to n-1 is likely to be faster on avg.

Comment: Using recursion purely as a looping mechanism is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recursively return the answer from the `gen` call like

```
def gen ():
  x=random.randint(0,10)
  isprime (x)
  if isprime(x):
   return x
  else:
   return gen()
```

Additionally, you may want to be sure that you use consistent indenting or the Python interpreter may complain about it.